# Was the continuation of Tsubasa Reservoir Chronicle ending in manga shown in Kobato?

Tags: tsubasa-chronicle, kobato

In Kobato Episode 20: "...The Travellers", Kobato met Syaoran, Fye, Kurogane and Mokona (all of them looked more mature for me and I think Kurogane and Fye both grew hair). Since Sakura wasn't with them, is it safe to assume that this episode is somehow a sneak peek of the continuation of Tsubasa Reservoir Chronicle ending in the manga showing their continuous journey?

Where,

> the epilogue ends with Syaoran deciding to go on a journey in order to try and find a way for the soul of clone Syaoran (who is his own father) to be restored to a body, Sakura has revealed that she had a dream which has given her a vision of the future so she can not go on the journey. Apparently in order to escape from the final prison of Fei Wong Reed, Syaoran gave up something. Syaoran gave up being able to settle down in one place so now he's traveling endlessly with Kurogane and Fye (who both decided to go with him) and of course Mokona (their transportation medium).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In episode 20 of Kobato, when Kobato mentions that Syaoran and his companions have been traveling for a long time and Syaoran says,

> "but it's a not journey with a destination. I guess you could say our destination is to continue travelling." When Kobato asks if it's undecided where they are going, he replies, "It would be difficult to decide. For one thing, we don't know how long we can stay in one place. But, I have someone waiting for me."

So it's definitely *after* the end of the Tsubasa Reservoir Chronicle epilogue published in October 2009, (Episode 20 of Kobato aired in March 2010):

> Syaoran is on his journey and they've been doing this for some considerable amount of time.  Where Syaoran went to look for a world where the clones can live, Sakura stayed in Clow because of her dream that she'd only cause sadness if she went with Syaoran, thus she is the one "waiting for me".

As far as I know, the October 7th epilogue was the last of the story, as a way to sort of tie up the loose ends. Kobato's crossover generated a lot of speculation about maybe getting more Tsubasa out of CLAMP, but [they announced in 2009 that the epilogue will be the end](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2009-09-17/clamp-to-end-tsubasa-reservoir-chronicle-on-october-7). There hasn't been any official news about the manga or continuing the story since. Though it wouldn't be surprising to see more crossovers with Syaoran, Fye, and Kurogane continuing their journey in future CLAMP productions.